# How do I replace "\r\n" with actual new lines in my source code?

Tags: visual-studio

I pasted some code* into Visual Studio, and the string literals have "\r\n" in them.  So a line will look like:

```
return "aaa\r\nbbb\r\nccc\r\n";
```

How can I replace each occurrence of "\r\n" with an actual line break?  I want this:

```
return @"aaa
bbb
ccc";
```

For similar replacements, I'd just do a simple find-and-replace.  But I don't know how to replace the text with a line break.  I tried copying and pasting a line break into the find-and-replace textbox, but it didn't work.

All of my searching tells me to do something like `myString.Replace("\r\n", Environment.Newline)`, but that won't work because I want to change the source code.

* *This happened when I ran a DLL through JetBrains DotPeek and exported it to a C# project.*

Comment: Edit > Find and Replace > Quick Replace.  Turn on regular expressions and replace `\\r\\n` with '\r\n`.  Tweaking the result is still required.  Just don't do this, the embedded \r\n is just fine.

Comment: @HansPassant, that was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.